# Why isn't cwnd restricted by rwnd in a TCP connection?

Tags: tcp, cwnd

I'm trying to understand how TCP works and I'm a bit surprised by the (absence of) effect of the receiver window (rwnd) on the congestion window (cwnd).
From what I've read (mainly [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control) and [RFC5681](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5681#section-3.1)) I understand that if the slow start threshold (ssthresh) has not been reached but the transmission rate is restricted by rwnd (since it is the minimum value between rwnd and cwnd) then cwnd continues to increase during the slow start phase (and even during congestion avoidance) if there are no loss or timeout. Meaning that cwnd could potentially reach a very high value since the initial value of ssthresh is extremely big.
See the following citation to confirm my deduction :

> Implementation Note: An easy mistake to make is to simply use cwnd,
> rather than FlightSize, **which in some implementations may
>
> incidentally increase well beyond rwnd**.
> [from RFC5681  (this part of the RFC is about setting a new value for ssthresh after a loss)]

In this case wouldn't it be possible to :

1. keep a connection with a relatively low transmission rate (e.g. setting rwnd to 10mss in every ack) to have no loss and hence keep the connection in the slow start phase,
2. wait enough time to allow cwnd to be extremely big (like 10 times what the link can handle) and then
3. set rwnd to an even bigger value to let the transmission rate be restricted only by cwnd ?

This would lead to a massive amount of congestion on the link, especially since it will take quite a lot of time for the server to notice the loss with a timeout and reset cwnd back to its initial value... and this may have a huge impact on other connections using the same link, or at least the same bottleneck link.

I would have imagined that once rcwnd is reached, slow start algorithm stops and congestion avoidance would begin to react to any new change in the network (or an increase in rwnd).

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21775731/20003316, Linux implementation of TCP does not allow cwnd to increase when the sending rate is application-controlled (= sending rate is controlled by rwnd and not cwnd).
By looking more in depth into this, I've found that in fact there is an RFC handling this question : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7661#page-10

*When in slow start* :

- if the number of ACK in the current window is smaller than 0.5*cwnd, then a TCP implementation must not increase the value of cwnd.
- if the number of ACK in the current window is greater or equal than 0.5*cwnd, then a TCP implementation must increase the value of cwnd as it would normally do.

*When not in slow start*:

- if the sending rate is restricted by rwnd and not cwnd and the number of ACK in the current window is smaller than 0.5*cwnd, then a TCP implementation must not increase cwnd.
- otherwise proceed as usual

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).